# scrapy, changing location for amazon.de doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I observe the following problem during scraping of `amazon.de`.
during collection, it (`amazon`) displaying information base on current (script) location, so some item is not available, for other prices are different then original price.

I have following `scrapy` code, to change location and **scrape** data:

```py
class AmazonSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'amazon'
    allowed_domains = ['www.amazon.de']
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.de/']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = {
            'locationType': 'LOCATION_INPUT',
            'zipCode': '10115',
            'storeContext': 'drugstore',
            'deviceType': 'web',
            'pageType': 'Detail',
            'actionSource': 'glow',
            'almBrandId': 'undefined'
        }

        yield scrapy.FormRequest(
            url='https://www.amazon.de/gp/delivery/ajax/address-change.html',
            formdata=data,
            callback=self.parse_pages
        )

    def parse_pages(self, response):
        url = 'https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Filter-Computer-Glasses-Headache-Vintage/dp/B091FYYDXB/ref=sr_1_95?dchild=1&keywords=kopfschmerzen&qid=1630410090&s=drugstore&sr=1-95'
        yield response.follow(
            url=url,
            dont_filter=True,
            callback=self.parse_product
        )
```

but even if we perform a location change call `address-change` it still showing wrong info, for the current location.

Could you please help with this? Looks like I'm missing some params or something else

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was to use a proxy manager, like zenscrape, with IPs location set to the country I want datas from.
If you find a solution with scrapy request and address-change, let me know !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).